# Expected ',' joining parts of a multi- clause condition in a Swift "If Case"

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, if-case

```
let age = 25      
if case 18...35 = age where age >= 21 { 
    print ("In Cool Demographic and of drinking age")
}
```

In Swift, when I type the code above, it says right before in "where", there's a little red line under the "w" and it says:

> expected ',' joining parts of a multi- clause condition

Is there any way to fix/ work around this?

Comment: Replace `where` with `,`.

Comment: What's the point of the `where age >= 21` if your `if case` is already checking if `age` is in the range 18 to 35? Why not simply do `if case 21...35 = age {` ?

Comment: or simply `if 21...35 ~= age`

Comment: Thank you all so much! It works now!